# What is Prosser & Ankovich in Blade Runner (1982)?

Tags: dialogue, blade-runner

In the movie *Blade Runner (1982)* I came across the notion of something called **Prosser & Ankovich**.

Here's some context:

> Eldon Tyrell: 66,000 **Prosser & Ankovich**. Hmm. Trade. Trade at--
>
> Computer: Blue entry. A Mr. J.F. Sebastian. 16417.
>
> Eldon Tyrell: At this hour? What can I do for you, Sebastian?

Does this name **Prosser and Ankovich** have any meaning or these are just random words used to describe some sort of a financial operation on the market?

Comment: There were two questions here. I've edit out the second one

Comment: From context, Prosser and Ankovich is the name of a firm trading on the stock market. What the firm does is irrelevant. Tyrell is a rich guy managing his stock portfolio.

Comment: @matt_black - That's certainly one (very likely) possibility. As OP has said though, it could also be a financial instrument. If I told you I had "*a Pullman & Bowie at 400 basis points"* you'd be forgiven for not knowing that this is in fact a kind of bond named after its creators.

Comment: @valorum I think we agree, when I said stock market I didn't mean to exclude other types of financial instrument.

Comment: The blue entry thing is about the key cards around Sebastian's neck. It challenges him for a blue card on the way up and Batty for a red card on the way down

Comment: @Valorum Oh, wow! I would've never guessed that! Where did you get that from? How come Batty had his own key card? Why would he ask Sebastian to help him get into the building then? Sorry if my questions seem stupid to you... I'm just a little bit confused about this thing.

Comment: @JConstantine - You can see the scene in the [linked script](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/blade-runner-1982.pdf). Batty got the cards from Sebastian('s corpse).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [1981 version](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/blade-runner-1982.pdf) of the script contains a little more dialogue that doesn't seem to have made it to the final cut.

> [Tyrell is lying in a huge bed muttering into a computer device.]
>
> **TYRELL:** Note to pantry milk still too hot.
> 300,000 of Tsin Tsin Vinyl;...sell.
> Sixty six thousand Prosser and Ankopitch trade at...

The implication (especially the sell order) is that these are stocks of various companies that Tyrell is trading because that's what wealthy people do to show how wealthy they are in films. Note that '*Tsin Tsin Vinyl*' isn't a real company and nor, it would appear, is '*Prosser and Ankopitch*'